# how do i detect UIButton's TouchUp event under UIView Gesture

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, xcode4.2

i have multiple buttons and i am adding them into the UIView. 
I have added TouchDown/TouchUp events to all the buttons. Upto this, everything is pretty simple and works perfect

But now my requirement is, i want to swipe on the view and while swiping, i want to detect the same TouchDown/TouchUp events under the swipe. (say on button's touchdown, i will change highlight image of button and on touchup it get back to its normal image)

Is it possible?

How could i achieve it?

Comment: you mean that on button's touch event you need to change the image of the unbutton??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072698/changing-image-on-uibutton-when-user-presses-that-button-on-an-iphone

Comment: hey Sarah, thanks for your reply, but i have already did this. my requirement is, i want to do same thing on UIView drag. I have search on net, i roughly git the idea about Gesture of UIView, but i dont really found any solution...so looking for it

Comment: you cannot detect the button events if your UIView is having any gesture as i have faced same problem in my app

Comment: @Sarah:
(1) i want to drag my fingure on the iphone screen
(2) while dragging, it will come on buttons, at that time i want change the highlighted image of the button which is under my fingure
(3) once i drag the fingure outside the button which was previously highlighted, i want to chage it back to normal image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you specifically need the swipe gesture?

There is this method which detects when your fingers slide across UIView:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

Maybe you can create a class that inherits from UIButton and add the touchesMoved method:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   // psuedo code
   [self setBackgroundImageForControlState:@"file.png"];
}
```

Then in the touches Ended method, you can swap a different image in:

```
// when finger is raised off the button
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   // psuedo code
   [self setBackgroundImageForControlState:@"file.png"];
}
```

Comment: i my case, i have a mm class and inside that file. i have wrapper objective class with cpp class...now i want to call wrapper's method from cpp method with the above functionality...this is what i am trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should hadle events like `UIControlEventTouchDragEnter` and `UIControlEventTouchDragExit`?
Not sure, but it seems to be a solution.

Comment: i tried to use this, but i could not understand what i need to do for uiview drag? and how could i detect uibutton's event uder it? i am not getting any way to do this