# BackgroundImage of UIButton sometimes did not change with touchUpInside event

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, touch-up-inside

The `UIButton` is set as following code:

```
UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 27, 27)];
[btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imgUp.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imgDown.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

If I touch the `btw` quickly, the `imgDown.png` will not appear but the action `btnPressed:` is fired. How could it be fixed? Any help is appreciated:)

Comment: visit this question might be usefull for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072698/changing-image-on-uibutton-when-user-presses-that-button-on-an-iphone

Comment: Have you tried with `forState:UIControlStateSelected` instead highlighted?

Comment: just try this [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imgDown.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

Comment: @Mat Yes i have tried UIControlStateSelected, not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code can solve the problem.

```
-(void)btnPressedDelay{

    //original code in btnPressed: method
}

- (void) btnPressed:(id)sender
{    

    [self performSelector:@selector(btnPressedDelay) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
// 0 did the magic here

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in your code:

```
[btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imgDown.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call the setHiglighted: method for the button (btn) inside of btnPressed: function.

Answer (score 0):

its working fine i will tested it pls check your images and try it :

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 27, 27)];
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rainy.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(btnPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view button];
```

Comment: If btnPressed: did nothing it may work fine. Here in mine code it will modal a viewcontroller. One solution is post by myself.