# Add Power Button to Calculator App

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am trying to create a "Power Button" for my calculator app that will turn the calculator on/off. I created the button:

```
-(IBAction) *Power;
```

Without the power button, the app starts with "0" in the LCD display, and my buttons are all working; but how can I tell my app that the LCD should display "" and the buttons cannot be manipulated until the power button is pressed? Would a simple if-then function work? Can I put -(IBAction) buttons within if-thens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `BOOL property`, that and check for `YES` in all the `IBACtions`.

You need to set it to `YES/NO` on the method `Power`, typically as:

Initiaze it with `NO` in your `init` or `viewDidLoad`, whichever is applicable.

```
-(IBAction) power{
    self.powerOn=!self.powerOn;
}

-(IBAction) otherMethod{
     if(self.powerOn){
         //do your stuff
     }
}
```

Also, method with pointer `-(IBAction) *Power;` is not that you need here.

Comment: I would go with enabling/disabling user interaction in the target action for the power button like mentioned above

Comment: @Mario: I didn't find enabling / disabling of user interactions. Although this is the best way, For this, he just need to put all outlets, textfileds to setEnabled:NO.

Comment: Works great, thanks. One more thing - how can I change the images of my UIButtons when I push the power button?

Comment: @GeorgeFriday: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072698/changing-image-on-uibutton-when-user-presses-that-button-on-an-iphone

Comment: Thanks for the link... This is somehow not working. I am trying to change the image of other buttons when the power button is pressed. I know I need to use setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unselectedImageName"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; but how do I implement it?

Comment: you need to implement it in the action method, or there may be option in IB, to set image and alternate image

Answer (score 1):

1) declare a variable to track power on/off

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) BOOL powerOn;
```

in viewDidLoad,
assign `_powerOn = NO; or _powerOn = YES;`

2) inside your power button pressed event,

```
-(IBAction) Power;{
    //if on, then off
    if(self.powerOn){
        //make display ""
        self.powerOn = NO;
    }else{ //if off, the on
        self.powerOn = YES;
        //make display "0"
    }
}
```

3) add following line as the 1st line in all other button click events

```
-(IBAction) otherMethod{
      if(!self.powerOn) return;

      //your code
}
```

Comment: This is working great, but my app starts with Power On by default. Can I change this somehow? Also, how can I change the images of all my buttons when the power button is pressed? I would like to simulate buttons that "light up" when power is on. Thanks!

Comment: Never mind how to start the app with Power Off. I didn't read the whole answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

You Need to create IBOutlets for your Buttons, to edit behaviors of them while running the app.
These IBOutlets are created like this:

```
IBOutlet UIButton *myPowerButton;
```

You need to link them with the button in Interface Builder where you created the Outlet for.
There you can specify the 'Enabled' behavior to be YES or NO, so you can make a Power Button to set if the user can work or not.
For further information please read Apples Documentation about IBOutlets and Buttons.

[UIButton Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006815)

Comment: I think this is the most elegant approach going by the idea. I would define an outletCollection, though, with all the buttons to enable/disable. Then in your powerOnOff method  -setUserInteractionEnabled: to YES/NO for these buttons and define the image for your disabled buttons in IB or code with -setImage:forState: UIControlStateDisabled.

Comment: You dont even need to set another picture because Apple's OS will grey the Buttons out so that you can clearly see which ones are usable and which ones are'nt.

Comment: I know, but in the comments to the accepted answer, the OP asked for setting the pictures of the disabled buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this way, assuming the title of the button is Power:

```
-(IBAction) Power
{
    if(self.powerOn)
    {
        //make display ""
        self.powerOn = NO;
        for (UIView* subView in self.view.subviews)
        {
          if ([subView isMemberOfClass:[UIButton class]] && subView.titleLabel.text != @"Power")
           subView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
         }
    }
    else
    { //if off, the on
        self.powerOn = YES;
        //make display "0"
    }
}
```

I would disable the User interaction of all other button when powerbutton is off.