# Change button image on click event

Tags: ios7, xcode5

I want to change button image. As when i click on the button it will change it's image and after the click the button will return in its normal form.I want to know how to implement this? Please help me.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072698/changing-image-on-uibutton-when-user-presses-that-button-on-an-iphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
    [sender setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    UIImage *buttonImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
    [sender setImage:buttonImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the "highlighted" state of your button right in Interface Builder, or use this code:

```
[self.button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"normal"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pressed"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Comment: when i click on the button at the very first time it has not change any image.

Comment: if you "click" too quickly (eg with a mouse in the Simulator), UIKit won't display the highlighted image. That's a system behaviour. You could override `touchesBegan/Ended` to set the `highlighted` property yourself, but I don't believe that's worth the hassle.

Answer (score 0):

first fix the `Backgroudimage is @"image1.jpeg"` in `xib`, then

```
- (IBAction)mybutton:(id)sender
{
 [_buttonrefrence setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"download.jpeg"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
}
```