# Objective C How can we change the background image of a button in just when it is clicked and then go back to normal?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

```
[myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_normal"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_highlighted"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_highlighted"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
myButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
```

I have tried this code and it is not working.

Comment: Have you tried [setBackgroundImage:forState:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1624016-setbackgroundimage?language=objc)?

Comment: you have to take button type as UIButtonTypeCustom and below link might be useful to you https://stackoverflow.com/a/1883996/5184217

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `setBackgroundImage:forState`. The `setImage:forState` changes the image which is on the same depth level as the button title. Additionally the `backgroundImage` is automatically fit to the button's view bounds. The `image` is not.

Answer (score 0):

Implement `onTouchDown` action of that button and set button background image in that function by `[btn setBackgroundImage: forState:]`